# External SDK for JAVA

Tags: eclipse, sdk

I have downloaded a third party SDK for developing applications, in particular, related to the biometrics. I have installed it in my computer. However, I don't know how to use it. 
I want to create applications using this SDK and Eclipse IDE. Do I need somehow to define a path in Eclipse to be able to use this SDK? As I understood it is only a folder full of .jar libraries. 
How to use this SDK in Eclipse? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you arent using a repository, you need to add an external dependency to your project.

```
right click on the project -> hit properties
select Java Build Path
select the Libraries tab
press "Add External JARs"
```

That should be it, see below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You manage the compilers through the Installed JRE's tab.

Go to Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs and add the new JRE there.